# Xamarin.Forms - Nested Styling Inheritance Like CSS?

Tags: css, xamarin, xamarin.forms, styling

Let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    Some text
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <div class="inner">
        Yet more text <span>and even more text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I apply the following CSS:

```
.outer {
    color: blue;
}
```

Then all of the text in that html will be blue - all of the divs inside the `.outer` div will inherit the property, no matter how far they're nested in.

Can I do something similar in Xamarin.Forms? Or if I have a bunch of Labels inside a StackLayout, for example, do I have to style every. single. label...?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Xaml styling. The crux is Xamarin Forms XAML Controls are separate components and have no information about styles applied to their parents. Thus they wont inherit styles applied to parents. 

One workaround will be to create styles without giving them a resource key. This way the style gets applied to all the controls for which it was created.

Comment: Have a look at [Style inheritance](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/inheritance/#Style_Inheritance_in_XAML).

Comment: @Curiousity - no, the link you referenced talks about style definitions inheriting from other style definitions, *not* elements inheriting from their parent element.

Answer (score 1):

What I chose to do was create a static styling class then apply the style either within the XAML itself or to the control in the constructor if it was applicable.That way you have the control to individually style items or have a standard style for a reusable control.

**StyleClass**

```
    public static class AppStyling
        {

         public static readonly Style Style_Page_Standard = new Style(typeof(Page))
            {
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter {Property =  Xamarin.Forms.Page.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = AppStyling.Color_GlobalBackground},
                    new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Page.PaddingProperty, Value = AppStyling.Padding_StandardPage},

                }
            };

        public static readonly Style Style_Button_Standard = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = AppStyling.Color_ButtonBackground},
                new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Button.TextColorProperty, Value = AppStyling.Color_ButtonText},
                new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Button.FontSizeProperty, Value = AppStyling.Font_Button},
                new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = AppStyling.Color_ButtonBorder},
                new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderRadiusProperty, Value = AppStyling.Radius_StandardButtonCorner},
                new Setter {Property = Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderWidthProperty, Value = 3},

            }
        };
}
```

**Implementation on Control**

```
public Custom_Button()
        {
            this.Style = AppStyling.Style_Button_Standard;
        }
```

**Implementation in XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.Views.MyContentPage"
             xmlns:styling="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Styling;assembly=MyNameSpace"
             Title="MyContentPageTitle"
             Style="{x:Static styling:AppStyling.Style_Page_Standard}">
```

There are also Global Resource declarations to look into in the Xamarin docs.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use CSS with Xamarin.Forms to style the XAML. It is a library by [David Rettenbacher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516071/david-rettenbacher?tab=profile) called **XamlCSS**.

It also supports WPF and UWP projects.

As of now, for Xamarin.Forms, the *Prerelease version 2.0.0-pre1* is recommended. You can download it from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlCSS.xamarinforms/2.0.0-pre1). A documentation for XamlCSS can be found in this [wiki article](https://github.com/warappa/XamlCSS/wiki/Getting-started). Or simply install by using `Install-Package XamlCSS.XamarinForms -Version 2.0.0` in *Package Manager Console*.

The best method to get an understanding is to try out the [sample project](https://github.com/warappa/XamlCSS).

Refer [this Forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67249/xamlcss-styling-xaml-applications-with-css) for more information.